# How to populate tableview with dictionary that matches the key for date

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, dictionary

Title is confusing I know but I have a dictionary with a date (string) key and event text as the value.

How do I first figure out which keys match the date for the next 30 days, then populate my tableview with whatever key/value pairs that are within those 30 days?

```
var calendarDataSource = [
    "08/12": "SomeData",
    "08/13": "SomeData",
    "08/14": "SomeData",
    "08/15": "SomeData",
    "08/16": "SomeData",
    "08/17": "SomeData",
    "08/18": "SomeData",
    "08/19": "SomeData",
    "08/20": "SomeData",
    "08/21": "SomeData",
    "08/22": "SomeData",
    "08/23": "SomeData",
    "08/24": "SomeData",
    "08/25": "SomeData"
]
```

Comment: Do you want to filter data set and get only elements with next 30 days?

Comment: Map the string dates to real `Date`s. This makes it easier to do the date math

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha yes. Then when I do cellforrowat, I can populate using only that second dictionary that only has elements with next 30 days. If that correct to do?

Comment: @MichaelScott Can you add Dictionary to question

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha Yes added what I have so far

Comment: @MichaelScott why are you use Dictionary for this.? Is it must or can we go to alternative ?

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha It doesn't have to be a Dictionary. I just don't know how to have a pair that I want. Have a date string and an event text for that same day

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try your code until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current date using a calendar to get the current month and day from your current date.

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
var month = 0
var day = 0
```

Once you have that I've created a `[String]()` to hold all the `KEYS` that will match your dictionary. I have then created a loop to count day 1 - 30 and add each date to that array for your reference w/ the dictionary. It's important to use the `.date(byAdding:...)` so that you can account for months that may have 28, 30, or 31 days.

```
var datesToPull = [String]()
for futureDay in 1...30{
    let toDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: futureDay, to: date)
    month = calendar.component(.month, from: toDate!)
    day = calendar.component(.day, from: toDate!)

    // We have to format the days to a XX/XX value to handle your key requirements. 
    datesToPull.append("\(String(format: "%02d", month))/\(String(format: "%02d", day))")
}
```

if you wish to count today as well simply change your loop to this

```
for futureDay in 0...30{...
```

Finally, to do something with those keys, place this inside of your `tableView(_ cellForRowAt:...)` method or wherever it suits your needs.

```
for key in calendarDataSource.keys{
    if datesToPull.contains(key){
        print("Date Found.")
    }
    else{
        print("No date found.")
    }
}
```

#### Note

*This will not preserve any sort of ordering. Which shouldn't matter due to using a Dictionary, but just in case you didn't know.*